# Sort a pandas datetime index

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a pandas datetime index that I construct.  It may be that through the construction process that the individual members are not in order.  I want to sort the index.  Is there an obvious way I should be doing this?

What I've done so far is this

```
import pandas as pd
tseries = pd.to_datetime(['2001-02-04', '2013-08-14', '2008-01-25'])
print 'original unsorted tseries'
for t in tseries:
    print t
tseries.values.sort()
print 'new sorted tseries'
for t in tseries:
    print t
```

output:

```
original unsorted tseries
2001-02-04 00:00:00
2013-08-14 00:00:00
2008-01-25 00:00:00
new sorted tseries
2001-02-04 00:00:00
2008-01-25 00:00:00
2013-08-14 00:00:00
```

What is the appropriate way to do this?  Is what I've done always expected to work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try

```
tseries.order()
```

If you work with a DataFrame, the term is called sort again, i.e. .sort() and .sort_index()

Comment: There's a sort too for a Series, the difference is that sort is inplace (and in <=0.13.1 uses slightly different sorting algo).