# python pandas String to TimeStramps convert ambigous

Tags: python, pandas, slice

I'm trying to slice a Dataframe using DateTimeIndex, but a got one issue.
When the new DataFrame Change Month, he switch the day and the month.

Here is my dataframe:

```
                     Valeur
    date                       
2015-01-08 00:00:00      93
2015-01-08 00:10:00      90
2015-01-08 00:20:00      88
2015-01-08 00:30:00     103
2015-01-08 00:40:00      86
2015-01-08 00:50:00      88
2015-01-08 01:00:00      86
2015-01-08 01:10:00      84
2015-01-08 01:20:00      95
2015-01-08 01:30:00      88
2015-01-08 01:40:00      85
2015-01-08 01:50:00      92
...                     ...
2016-10-30 22:20:00      98
2016-10-30 22:30:00      94
2016-10-30 22:40:00      94
2016-10-30 22:50:00     103
2016-10-30 23:00:00      92
2016-10-30 23:10:00      85
2016-10-30 23:20:00      98
2016-10-30 23:30:00      96
2016-10-30 23:40:00      95
2016-10-30 23:50:00     101

[65814 rows x 1 columns]
```

Here my two TimeStamps:

```
startingDate : 2015-10-31 23:50:00
lastDate : 2016-10-30 23:50:00
```

When i slice my df like this :

```
dfconso = dfconso[startingDate:lastDate]
```

i got something like this :

```
                         Valeur
date                       
2015-10-31 23:50:00      88
2015-01-11 00:00:00      83
2015-01-11 00:10:00      82
2015-01-11 00:20:00      87
2015-01-11 00:30:00      77
2015-01-11 00:40:00      72
2015-01-11 00:50:00      86
2015-01-11 01:00:00      77
2015-01-11 01:10:00      80
...                     ...
2016-10-30 23:10:00      85
2016-10-30 23:20:00      98
2016-10-30 23:30:00      96
2016-10-30 23:40:00      95
2016-10-30 23:50:00     101
```

The problem is the slice start at the good date, but when the DateTimeIndex change month, something wrong append.
Pass from 31 October 2015 to 11 January 2015.

And i don't understand why..

I try to print the month and day to see and i got that :

In:

```
print("Index 0 : month", dfconso.index[0].month, ", day", dfconso.index[0].day)
print("Index 1 : month", dfconso.index[1].month, ", day", dfconso.index[1].day)
```

Out:

```
Index 0 : month 10 , day 31
Index 1 : month 1 , day 11
```

If someone has an idea

EDIT :

After df.sort_index() my df, i can see the convert of String date to TimeStamps date, didn't work sometimes, and switch Month and Day.

Format at String :

```
"31/08/2015 20:00:00"
```

My code to transform from String to TimeStamps:

```
dfconso.index = pd.to_datetime(dfconso.index, infer_datetime_format=True, format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION :

that was a bad use of pd.to_datetime, i change infer_date_time_format to Dayfirst :

```
dfconso.index = pd.to_datetime(dfconso.index, dayfirst=True)
```

That solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error might not be a mixup of day and month, but just an ordering problem. Try reordering the data before slicing it (the provided part of your data looks fine, but who knows about the rest..).

Here is how reordering works: [Sort a pandas datetime index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993603/sort-a-pandas-datetime-index)

Comment: After sorting i can see that pandas invert my Month date and Day date sometimes. i will try to see my convert method.